# Can a question be an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Yesterday, I flagged a question as NAA, the question was:

> Did you remember to run qmake after adding the resource file?

and the flag was declined with the reason:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Since this answer *is* a question (it's asking for more information about OP's original question), was I wrong to flag as NAA?

Should I have reformulate for something like:

> You should try to run `qmake` after adding the resource file.

Or should I have took any other action?

Comment: That's just the usual NAA ambiguity. There's even a prepared comment for the review queue as "requesting further information should be done in a comment", so I guess a mod declined your flag, because if you press your eyes together and look at this post in a certain angle, then you can see an answer in it.

Comment: I think, rewording the "answer" would be a good action. I would go for: "You have to run _qmake_ after adding the resource file."

Comment: It is a better guess at the correct answer than the upvoted answer.  And the kind of answer that's forced by the Q, it isn't answerable without guessing.  And actually *looks* like a guess, that has merit given that it is a guess.  It could be very easily edited to not look like a guess, like "A simple explanation for this mishap is forgetting to run qmake after editing the resource file".