# Has there been a change in how flags are reviewed?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, late-answers

Recently my flags about "low quality answer" started being declined. So much so that I am now banned from flagging. All that is fine, except I don't think I made any change in how I review flags.

An example of this are "late answers" with the following structure:

> [Your problem] MIGHT be happening because of [some reason]. Have you tried [Suggestion]?

This looks to me like a comment. It asks for more information and suggests some possible thing that might be causing the issue. It's just two sentences. So in the past I flagged all answers like this as "low quality" and majority of them were closed with "this is a comment not an answer to the question".

But now all they are being declined with "inaccurate or wrong answers shouldn't be flagged" reason. Is there any new policy I missed or just some coincidence?

Comment: Were you using the "not an answer" flag?

Comment: @Makoto no, all the declined flags were "low-quality answer" flags.

Comment: Strongly related: [Is “very short answer” an answer or comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350305/7795130), [Can a suggestion be an answer or does it need to be a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346147/7795130), [Can I answer if I'm not sure?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370133/7795130) and [Can a question be an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349234/7795130). All together, the format you have described is a valid answer and will be helpful to viewers if the suggestion is what fixes the problem, and should be downvoted if it is wrong, not flagged.

Comment: @DavyM thanks, this is useful. So I might have been flagging wrongly in several situations in the past.

Comment: That looks like it's the case. Though in part it's fault of the reviewers who led to your flags being marked helpful so you never realized that the previous flags were wrong until now. But the good news is that now you know, and you can improve your flagging now. *[The more you know...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zmvt7yFTtt8)*

Comment: possibly related: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/839601) (although without moderator check of past helpful flags there is no way to tell for sure)

Comment: I believe the flags on answers to be of little use unless the answer is a clear case of something absolutely incorrect for the site. I generally downvote if it's a bad answer, but leave it to people with delete vote privileges to deal with actually making them disappear.

Comment: Of your last 17 flags, all but two were handled by a single moderator. 5 of the 15 they handled were declined, all others accepted (and the answers deleted). Looking over all these, I probably would have acted the same way around these flags. As for why you saw more declined flags recently, your older flags tended to be on things that were more clearly non-answers when compared to these. Also, the moderator flag queue is at a fairly low level now, causing more of the "very low quality" flags to be acted on by moderators instead of review.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for looking so thoroughly into this. So it seems like you did see a change in the flags when comparing the more recent ones with the older ones. Hm I guess that is possible. Maybe seeing that most all of my older flags were accepted I got more liberal in raising them.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius I started seeing this change too recently. Earlier my flags in the category _This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether_ passed. But when I flagged the answer _I use tensorflow 1.9.0, and it works fine, maybe it has been fixed from some version of tensorflow._ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827370/map-fn-with-dynamic-shape-tensor/51832566#51832566) it falied.

Comment: The comment was _flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer_. I though that is not the flagged category.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Yes exactly, those types of answeres is what I was talking about. Your example has it: very low quality, barely a sentence. The answerer didn't even bother to check if the problem indeed was fixed with the newer version and. Just said that it works for him and MAYBE was fixed. IMO these type of answers are lower quality compared to link-only answers, which everyone deletes.

Answer (score 11):

[Comments are intended to be used to...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been updated).

An answer that tries to answer the question (identifying a likely cause for the problem, suggesting a solution) doesn't fall into any of those categories; it may be *wrong*, but it's still an answer.

Comment: the question seems to imply that until recently flags raised by OP somehow managed to pass as helpful despite the guidance you quoted and OP looks like interested in why would that be (my guess is their flags were handled in LQ queue and didn't reach moderators but I can't see flag history to say for sure)

Comment: @gnat to clarify - this quoted guidance is about comments, I didn't flag the answers as "should be a comment", simply as "low quality". Just that a big proportion of them were closed with the reason "should be a comment..", which was probably selected by somebody else. I would put some examples of past flags, but the answers of all non-declined flags are already deleted, and I can't remember what they were.

Comment: _identifying a likely cause for the problem_ is not the same as _requesting clarification from the author_? If their **assumption** is wrong, that answer isn't valid for the question, to me that should be classified as requesting clarification

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: When the answer is wrong, then downvote it. Beeing wrong is not a reason to delete an answer.

Comment: @BDL Even if the answer isn't even relevant at all to the question? I'm just saying that if a person is only assuming what the problem is, this would be better suited as a comment, wouldn't it?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Stating possible reasons and solutions for it **is** relevant to the question. Even if it's not the cause of op's problem, it might help future visitors who have the same problem but a different root cause. If the answer is completely unrelated, then that's another thing.

Comment: [Psychic debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050321-00/?p=36123) @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the link. And I appreciate the discussion BDL.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton "If the problem is X, do Y. Otherwise, do Z and tell me what is the result" is a valid answer. -- {paraphrase. source unknown}

Comment: @user202729 The amount of uncertainty in it makes it _feel_ more like a comment to me, but I understand what you're saying.

Comment: The question title is "Has there been a change in how flags are reviewed?"  This answer does not address that.

Comment: Because the answer to that question is boring, @chux. How flags are handled changes *all the time* as different people handle them; what's important is that the right stuff gets flagged to begin with.